# How to call extension functions from generic code

Tags: kotlin

Given the following classes and extension functions

```
class Foo 
class Bar

fun Foo.run() = "Foo.run"
fun Bar.run() = "Bar.run"

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = listOf(Foo(), Bar())
    val y = x.map({a -> a.run()}) //compiler error
    println("Hello, world!")
}
```

is it possible to call `run` in a generic way?

Somehow this is an attempt to emulate Swift's `protocol`s and `extension`s when extending a class via an interface or is either not **possible or undesireable**.

Comment: Why don't you give them a common type (e.g. interface) and extend this one instead?

Comment: doesn't work on sealed classes

Comment: You can make it work with sealed, see my answer

Comment: I have updated my uestion slightly as my initial example seemed to indicate a common function impl. which it does not have

Answer (score 1):

You simply need a common type and extend this one instead. A simple marker **interface** will help here:

```
interface Common
class Foo: Common
class Bar: Common

fun Common.run() = "run"

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = listOf(Foo(), Bar())
    val y = x.map {a -> a.run() }
}
```

Or with **`sealed` classes** (as you suggested in the OP):

```
sealed class Common {
    class Foo: Common()
    class Bar: Common()
}

fun <T: Common> T.run() = "run"

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = listOf(Common.Foo(), Common.Bar())
    val y = x.map {a -> a.run() }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list has the lowest common type for `Foo` and `Bar` -- `Any`, you are ought to check for type in your lambda before calling `run` method:

```
class Foo
class Bar

fun Foo.run() = "Foo.run"
fun Bar.run() = "Bar.run"

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = listOf(Foo(), Bar())
    val y = x.map({ a ->
        when (a) {
            is Foo -> a.run()
            is Bar -> a.run()
            else -> {
                /* ignore */
            }
        }
    })
    println("Hello, world!")
}
```

or

```
class Foo
class Bar

fun Foo.run() = "Foo.run"
fun Bar.run() = "Bar.run"

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = listOf(Foo(), Bar())
    val y = x.map({ a ->(a as? Foo)?.run() ?: (a as? Bar)?.run() })
    println("Hello, world!")
}
```

Since the inferred type of elements in `x` is `Any`, it can contain elements other than `Foo` and `Bar`, so your code won't find the method for such element and this is checked at compile time.

And even if you add extension function with reified type check, it will be converted to lowest common parent:

```
class Foo
class Bar

fun Foo.run() = "Foo.run"
fun Bar.run() = "Bar.run"
fun Any.run() = "Any.run" // this is type erasured version of 'inline fun <reified T> T.run() = T::class.simpleName+".run"'

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = listOf(Foo(), Bar())
    val y = x.map(Any::run)
    println(y)
}
```

will print `[Any.run, Any.run]`

But using the reference to `this` you can provide data to your function like:

```
class Foo 
class Bar 

inline fun Any.run() = this::class.simpleName + ".run"

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = listOf(Foo(), Bar())
    val y = x.map(Any::run)
    println(y)
}
```

will print `[Foo.run, Bar.run]`

You can also move code dispatching child class type to an extension function like this:

```
class Foo
class Bar

fun Foo.run() = "Foo!!!.run"
fun Bar.run() = "Bar!!!.run"
fun Any.run() = when(this){
    is Foo -> run()
    is Bar -> run()
    else -> { "Unknown.run" }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = listOf(Foo(), Bar(), Any())
    val y = x.map({ a -> a.run()
    })
    println(y)
}
```

will print `[Foo!!!.run, Bar!!!.run, Unknown.run]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
fun <T> T.run() = "run"
```

This `run` definition should make the rest of your code compile.

If you want to limit the callees of `run`, you should create a common `sealed class` like this.

```
class Foo : Bla()
class Bar : Bla()
sealed class Bla

fun <T : Bla>.run() = "run"

// this works, too
// fun Bla.run() = "run"
```

In this way, only instances of `Foo` and `Bar` can use `run`.

But if I were you, I'd make `run` a member function of `Bla`.

Comment: I am rather looking to express "any type that has a (different) `run` function" instead of limiting it

Comment: This is impossible, except you're glad to use reflection.